# Overwriting image on amazon s3. In mobile overwritten image still shows. However in desktop, new (correct) image shows. why? caching issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, angularjs, caching, amazon-s3

I have a simple app that requires a profile. The first page creates your profile and the second page allows you to upload an image. When the first page is creating your profile, it uploads to amazon s3 a generic image, just in case you decide not to choose an image on page 2. The link to this generic image is saved in your profile.

If you do choose to upload an image on page 2, the same link is overwritten by the new image you upload.

In this way, there is only 1 link for your profile regardless of a generic or specified photo.

After page 2, you are in the app's main page. Here there is an option to go back to page 2, so that you can change your image if you want

When you go back to page 2, it's supposed to show you the image you currently have, by doing a simple img src to the link reserved for your profile.

Something odd happens here however.

On desktop, the image is correct. That is, the generic image is no longer showing and the correct one is in it's place. On mobile however, the generic image remains.

I don't understand why there is an issue on mobile but not desktop.

Is this because my mobile phone is caching the first image considering that the link has not changed? If so, how do I fix this? Alternatively, is this an angular JS issue where I need to use $scope.apply()? Or alternatively, is this an amazon S3 issue?

I don't think this is either an amazon s3 or angular js issue because that would not explain why it's still working on desktop. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your mobile caches the old image. It's normal because mobile app frameworks like phonegap cache images with a tougher rule than desktop (you know in most countries mobile bandwidth is relatively expensive).

The solution is simple: add a "time value" after image url like this so that the mobile will recognize it as another image. But you might need to rewrite your code to re-render dynamic images.

```
var image_url = original_imgage_url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
document.write('<img src="'+image_url+'" />');
```